# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'group' not found when using ggplot to make a map of Antarctica

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot some points on a map of Antarctica:

I have this code:

```
#Map Antarctica
world <- map_data("world")
worldmap <- ggplot(world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group) +
  geom_path() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=(-2:2) * 30) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=(-4:4) * 45)
```

I tried this to plot some points but without success and I'm getting the following error

```
#Plot counting points
plot(worldmap + coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(-90, 0, 0))) +
  geom_point(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), data = penguin_trim,
             alpha = .5, color="darkred", size = 3)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'group' not found"
```

I also tried this:

```
ggplot() +
  worldmap + 
  coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(-90, 0, 0)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), data = penguin_trim)
```

and got the same error

I'm new to R and cannot think of another way to add the points to my map.. Any suggestions??

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your call to `ggplot` is missing a closing paren (after `aes(..)`), is that a typo here or in your code as well?

Comment: Where is the penguin_trim data from? Can you show the first 2 rows, do you expect a group variable to be there?

Comment: Welcome to SO, dorina! This is a *great* first question! If I might add two suggestions: (1) please be explicit about non-base graphics that are not obvious based on the tags. In this case, I believe `library(maps)` resolves it, but if I'm incorrect, then my answer (and assumptions) could be incorrect. (2) As @rdodhia already suggested, you reference `penguin_trim` but we don't know what it is. We can infer (and I guessed on the needed structure in my answer), but it would help to include the output from `dput(head(penguin_trim,3))` (or so) in your question. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the answers, it really helped! And thanks for the feedback too, I should've added the other bit of code too with 'penguin_trim' data so that would be more explicit. That was a .csv file with coordinate data for counting points of penguin population.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `penguin_trim`, this is a guess: `group` is present in `world` but not in `penguin_trim`. You can confirm this with `"group" %in% names(penguin_trim)`.

One way to resolve this is to move the `group=group` aesthetic into the geoms plotting the worldmap stuff:

Try this:

```r
library(maps)
worldmap <- ggplot(world, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +    # remove group=group from here
  geom_path(aes(group = group)) +                      # add aes(group=group) here
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=(-2:2) * 30) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=(-4:4) * 45)
worldmap +
  coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(-90, 0, 0)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), data = penguin_trim,
             alpha = .5, color="darkred", size = 3)
```

The issue is that by putting it in the "global" `ggplot` aesthetics definitions, ggplot2 will search for `group` in *all* datasets you add to the plot in later geoms. Another option would be to *not* inherit from the global side:

```r
worldmap <- ggplot(world, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_path() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=(-2:2) * 30) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=(-4:4) * 45)
worldmap +
  coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(-90, 0, 0)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), data = penguin_trim,
             inherit.aes = FALSE,                      # add this
             alpha = .5, color="darkred", size = 3)
```

Unless I'm mistaken, though, the `group=group` is specific to the geoms needed for plotting coasts and such, so perhaps it should stay in the geom(s) dealing with the world data.

A third option is to make `penguin_trim` the primary data, and only use `world` for its one geom:

```r
pengplot <- ggplot(penguin_trim, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) +
  coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(-90, 0, 0)) +
  geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = world) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=(-2:2) * 30) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=(-4:4) * 45) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, color = "darkred", size = 3)
```

This has an advantage that if you're going to add more layers from `penguin_trim`, the data is the default data.

[image]

I also changed two things that may be minor:

- I added a close-paren `)` after `ggplot(world, aes(..)`; and
- I removed the `plot(.)` around `worldmap + coord_map(.)`

---

Sample data:

```r
penguin_trim <- structure(list(longitude = c(0, 90, 180, -90), latitude = c(-85, -80, -75, -70)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```